# How can I resolve the 'Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression' warning in webpack when using PurgeCSS?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, purgecss

In the webpack build process, seeing this warning

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.es.js 397:18-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./src/utils/renderPage.js
 @ ./src/server.js
```

In the renderPage i'm using purgecss like this

```
import PurgeCSS from 'purgecss';

function purgeCSS(css, htmlBody, verticalName, isAmp) {
  const { whitelist, whitelistPatternsChildren } = getWhitelists(test, testName, [], []);
  const purgecss = new PurgeCSS({
  });
  const [] = purgecss.purge();
  const {} = purgeCssResult;

  return cleanCSS;
}
```

I tried below steps:

1. adding `new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/purgecss[\\/]lib/, false),` but this is causing errors and failing to load css
2. using alias - `alias: { purgecss: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/purgecss/purgecss'), },`
3. using `purgecss: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/purgecss/lib'),`

`"webpack": "^4.44.1", "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0", "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0", "purgecss": "^1.4.2",`